# Изменить свойство css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

У меня есть скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toogle_mmenu").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("top_nav_on");
    $(".mmenu_top").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Теперь надо после добавления класса `.top_nav_on` изменить свойство класса `.top_nav` (добавить `margin-bottom: 500px;` классу `.top_nav`)

Помогите!

Comment: добавьте это свойство в .top_nav_on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toogle_mmenu").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("top_nav_on");
    if ($(this).hasClass("top_nav_on"))
      $(".top_nav").css("margin-bottom", 500);
    else
      $(".top_nav").removeAttr("style");
    $(".mmenu_top").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: И это как удалить изменении свойства когда этого класса нет?top_nav_on создается что бы открыть drop menu кликаеш еще раз и top_nav_on удаляется а margin-bottom", 500 остается

Comment: @ФаильХабибуллин, добавил условие в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = ".top_nav {margin-bottom: 500px;}";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

Возникает лишь вопрос зачем? Не проще создать отдельный класс (если уж надо), в котором будет прописано это свойство, и добавить его к элементам `.top_nav`? Не говоря уже о записи свойства в добавляемом классе, ну или на крайняк, добавлении его через jQ

Comment: .mmenu_top абсолютный элемент маргины не видит а .top_nav релатив

Comment: @ФаильХабибуллин и?

Comment: Абсолютный элемент перекрывает блок внизу